# Returns the string represention of the timespan between two dates JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date

I have the following task: Returns the string represention of the timespan between two dates. The format of output string is `"HH:mm:ss.sss"`. I wrote the following code:

```
function timeSpanToString(startDate, endDate) {
 const zero = '0';
 let hours = endDate.getHours() - startDate.getHours();
 let minutes = endDate.getMinutes() - startDate.getMinutes();
 let sec = endDate.getSeconds() - startDate.getSeconds();
 let ms = endDate.getMilliseconds() - startDate.getMilliseconds();
 hours = hours < 10 ? zero + hours : hours;
 minutes = minutes < 10 ? zero + minutes : minutes;
 sec = sec < 10 ? zero + sec : sec;
 if (ms < 10) {
  ms = zero + zero + ms;
 }
 if (ms >= 10 && ms < 100) {
  ms = zero + ms;
 }
 return `${hours}:${minutes}:${sec}.${ms}`;
}
```

And I have the following tests:

```
        {
            startDate: new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,0),
            endDate:   new Date(2000,1,1,11,0,0),
            expected:  '01:00:00.000'
        }, {
            startDate: new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,0),
            endDate:   new Date(2000,1,1,10,30,0),
            expected:  '00:30:00.000'
        }, {
            startDate: new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,0),
            endDate:   new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,20),
            expected:  '00:00:20.000'
        }, {
            startDate: new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,0),
            endDate:   new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,0,250),
            expected:  '00:00:00.250'
        }, {
            startDate: new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,0),
            endDate:   new Date(2000,1,1,15,20,10,453),
            expected:  '05:20:10.453'
        }, {
            startDate: new Date(2000,1,1,10,0,0),
            endDate:   new Date(2000,1,2,15,20,10,453),
            expected:  '29:20:10.453'
```

The problem is in the last test.

[image: Last test]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Made it easier:

```
 var rez = endDate - startDate;
 let h = Math.trunc(rez / 3600000 % 100).toString().padStart(2, '0');
 let m = Math.trunc(rez / 60000 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
 let s = Math.trunc(rez / 1000 % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
 let ms = Math.trunc(rez % 1000).toString().padStart(3, '0');
 return (h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.' + ms);
```